# Disable Autosave when taking screenshot on UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I just upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

In ubuntu 16.04 when I trigger the screenshot shortcut, the notification about save/copy to clipboards/name will popped up.

However, in 18.04 when I triggered the shortcut, it will automatically save to ~/Pictures

I just want the behavior the same with 16.04

How to achieve that?